# Read a binary file and store all data into array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, structure, binaryfiles

I need to write a program which simply a measurement conversion program.
The program first ask the user for name of a binary file (unit conversion data), open the file, and set arrays.

My structure:

```
struct unit {               
    char name[NAME_LEN];        
    char abbrev[ABBREV_LEN];    
    char class[CLASS_LEN];                                      
    double standard;            
};
```

and my function:

```
int fread_units(int unit_max,struct unit units[], int *unit_sizep)
{
    FILE *filep;
    struct unit data;
    int i, status;
    char fullname[10];

    /* Gets database of units from file                                 */

    printf("Enter name of binary file> ");
    scanf("%s", fullname);
    strcat(fullname, ".bin");
    i = 0;
    filep = fopen(fullname, "rb");
    //fseek (filep , 0 , SEEK_END);
    for (status = fread(&data, sizeof( struct unit ), 1, filep);
         status == 1 && i < unit_max;
         status = fread(&data, sizeof( struct unit ), 1, filep)){
        units[i++] = data;
    }
    printf("\n%f", units[3].standard);
    /* Issue error message on premature exit                            */
    if (status == 0) {
        printf("\n*** Error in data format ***\n");
        printf("*** Using first %d datavalues ***\n",i);
    }
    else if (status != EOF) {
        printf("\n*** Error: too much data in file ***\n");
        printf("*** Using first %d data values ***\n", i);
    }

    /* Send back size of used portion of array                          */
    *unit_sizep = i;

    if(status == 4)
        status = 1;
    else if (status != EOF)
        status = 0;
    fclose(filep);

    return(status);
}
```

According to the book, `(fread(&data, sizeof( struct unit ), 1, filep);)` is enough to store all data into a structure.

But it doesn't work for me...

Output:

```
*** Error in data format ***
*** Using first 4 datavalues ***
To convert 25 kilometers to miles, you would enter
> 25 kilometers miles
    or, alternatively,
>   25 km mi
> 25 km mi
Attempting conversion of 25.0000 km to mi . . .
Unit kmnot in database

Enter a conversion problem or q to quit.
>
```

my units.bin file;

```
miles                   mi          distance        1609.3
kilometers              km          distance        1000
yards                   yd          distance        0.9144
meters                  m           distance        1
quarts                  qt          liguid_volume   0.94635
liters                  l           liquid_volume   1
gallons                 gal         liquid_volume   .7854
millimeters             ml          liquid_volume   0.001
kilograms               kg          mass            1
grams                   g           mass            0.001
slugs                   slugs       mass            0.14594
```

Comment: Wait, is your units.bin file a **text** file? How is `standard` field really saved?

Comment: Your struct says that the last field is a  `double`, but your file contains a _textual representation of the number_! You have to do something else to read the textual number and then convert it to an actual double.

Comment: How can I create a binary file to work on it?

Comment: How many items did the `for` loop process?  If the `fread` reads beyond the end of the file, it will return 0 since no items exist past the end of the file.

Comment: Well - if you are happy with your formatted text file you should look into fscanf() for formatted reading instead of fread().

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should place your solution in an answer and accept it.  Preferably with an explanation of what changes you needed to make to fix your problem.

Comment: @guguk: You shall also click the check icon next to your answer. This will mark your answer as the correct one, hence there will be no need to change your question title as "(solved)"

Comment: I can't click the check icon.
It says "you can accept your answer tomorrow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.I created a binary file with following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAME_LEN    30  
#define ABBREV_LEN  15  
#define CLASS_LEN   20  
#define MAX_UNITS   20  

struct unit {               
    char name[NAME_LEN];        
    char abbrev[ABBREV_LEN];    
    char class[CLASS_LEN];                                      
    double standard;            
};

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    struct unit unitp[MAX_UNITS];
    FILE *inp, *outp;
    inp = fopen("units.dat", "r");
    outp = fopen("units.bin", "wb");
    for(i=0;!feof(inp);i++){
        fscanf(inp, "%s%s%s%lf", unitp[i].name,
                                    unitp[i].abbrev,
                                    unitp[i].class,
                                    &unitp[i].standard);
    }
    fwrite(unitp, sizeof(struct unit ), i, outp);

    fclose(inp);
    fclose(outp);

    return(0);
}
```

and my for loop;

```
for (status = fread(&units[i++], sizeof( struct unit ), 1, filep);
     i < MAX_UNITS && !feof(filep);
     status = fread(&units[i++], sizeof( struct unit ), 1, filep)){
    //units[i++] = data;
}
```